# how to merge all files from multiple path stored in a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

how to merge all files from multiple path stored in a variable in python?

Below, I have tried to get all path in a veriable:

```
SUR_INVOICE_FILES = []
listoffolders = []
dir = path_in
inbound = dbutils.fs.ls (dir)
for folder in inbound:
    subfolderlist = dbutils.fs.ls(folder.path)   
    for listoffolders in subfolderlist:
        list_of_sources= listoffolders.path
        SR = dbutils.fs.ls(list_of_sources)
        SUR_INVOICE_FILES.append(listoffolders.path)
        root = (''+re.search('(/\w+)+.+',list_of_sources).group())
        print(root)
```

'root' gave me all path of files:

```
/mnt/datalake/**/SurInvoice/2020-08-31_093551/SurInvoice.parquet
/mnt/datalake/**/SurInvoice/2020-08-31_103115/SurInvoice.parquet
/mnt/datalake/**/SurInvoice/2020-09-01_075931/SurInvoice.parquet
/mnt/datalake/**/SurInvoice/2020-09-17_080933/SurInvoice.parquet
```

Now I want to `merge` all the contents of `parquet files` in one single file and store it in a differnet directory in `JSON` format. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Read with pandas, concatenate the data frames and then write to a json file. Something like this

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
for file_path in file_paths :
    dfs.append(pd.read_parquet(file_path))
df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
df.to_json(path)
```

Adding this to your code. See if this works :

```
SUR_INVOICE_FILES = []
listoffolders = []
dfs = []
dir = path_in
inbound = dbutils.fs.ls (dir)
for folder in inbound:
    subfolderlist = dbutils.fs.ls(folder.path)   
    for listoffolders in subfolderlist:
        list_of_sources= listoffolders.path
        SR = dbutils.fs.ls(list_of_sources)
        SUR_INVOICE_FILES.append(listoffolders.path)
        root = (''+re.search('(/\w+)+.+',list_of_sources).group())
        dfs.append(pd.read_parquet(root))
        print(root)
df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
df.to_json(save_path)
```

Comment: 'file_paths' is ->'root' for me(all parquet file paths of source) and 'path' is the destination path is it? With same i'm getting error -> Found files in an intermediate directory: /